# How can I customize the Isotope for Wordpress plugin?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, jquery-masonry, jquery-isotope

I recently added Metafizzy's [Isotope](http://isotope.metafizzy.co/) to my wordpress page, but I had some trouble linking it to my posts. As a solution I removed the code I had put in manually, and installed [this Isotope for Wordpress](http://mintthemes.com/isotope-for-wordpress/#comment-2185) plugin.

Has anyone used this and customized it using Isotope's different methods and layout modes? I'm having some trouble locating those key pieces of code (that are so easy to edit when you add isotope manually). This plugin seems to make editing them a bit trickier. If anyone could point me in the right direction I'd really appreciate it.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The isotope is function is called in the includes>js folder in the file called load_isotope.js

You can see the layout mode on line 6. Probably adding that functionality to the plugin would be a good idea.

Comment: Hey Phil would you know happen to know if 'hentry' would be the correct class to specify when using isotope's add items feature? Or should I somehow try to call the <div <?php post_class(); ?>> PHP within that .js file?
 
var $items = $('<div class="hentry" /> <div class="hentry" /> <div class="hentry" />');
 
$('#insert').click(function() {
        $('.mintthemes_isotopes_container').isotope( 'insert', $items );  });